# None of my assets are loading from my rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Some of my assets stopped loading on local. I tried:

`rake tmp:cache:clear`

`rake assets:clean`

`rake assets:clobber`

and then

`rake assets:precompile`

after I did that i got even *more* of these errors than before those commands:

`GET /assets/application.self-60df922d9e18a377003de2b30c64d5bf97ede1dd247b2c01c78528867d89d22f.css`

`GET /assets/local_time.self-128a04d66b2846a17e046fdf49e35ae00618c9e472c0021c2f949a8d17f7a9a8.js`

`GET /assets/bootstrap.min.self-075878ec6a19d24f3b46052eb9e0e5bb5c2a098ac50d05d8e3a21309d129273a.js`

etc etc.

**assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pages.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( dashboard.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( initial_settings.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( settings.css )
```

application.rb

```
.
.
.
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components')
.
.
.
```

**application.js**

```
// = require jquery
// = require jquery.turbolinks
// = require jquery_ujs
// = require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
// = require metisMenu.min
// = require sb-admin-2
// = require local_time
// = require bootstrap.min
// = require turbolinks
// = require_tree .
```

**application.scss**

```
 *= require_self
 *= require pages
 *= require sb-admin-2
 *= require metisMenu.min
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= timeline
 */

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
    font-family: "avenir next", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**environments/development.rb**

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
```

Usually I can just go back to an old commit and get things to work, and work my way back through the changes, but even when I rollback, I get these errors.

I'm using ngrok, so I can see all of these requests end in a 500 error, and the GET request is to the same asset name regardless of if I `rake assets:clean`. I'm not changing the assets either, so maybe the file name isn't suppose to  change, but maybe there's a caching problem?

When I run assets:precompile, it looks as if my `application.js` and `application.scss` are not getting precompiled, even though my `assets.rb` file says:

`# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.`

Comment: You're sure `config.assets.enabled = true`?

Comment: @AnthonyE yes. (In Rails 3.1+, the asset pipeline is enabled by default). I added that line just in case in my `development.rb` file and got the same result.